# using graphql github api to get commit information by Id

Tags: graphql, github-api, github-graphql

I would like to get commit details for a specific commit given that I already have the commit id

for example, if I know the commit id is 
 `12762b76cba8ac4623a6c16e1fe60efafa3b7d1c` and the repo is `ruby/ruby`

how do I get the committedDate and author email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a [cursor](https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/connections.htm#sec-Cursor) as an edge type, as in [this thread](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-API-Development-and/GraphQL-Why-using-quot-last-quot-in-quot-history-quot-return/td-p/23392):

```
{
  repository(owner: "octocat", name: "Hello-World") {
    first: object(expression: "master") {
      ... on Commit {
        history(path: "README", last: 1, before: "762941318ee16e59dabbacb1b4049eec22f0d303 1") {
          edges {
            node { 
              committedDate 
              oid
              author
              {  
                email
              }
            } 
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

you can test it using this explorer https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/

Comment: this works as long as you don't need the last commit. if you go to 
https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/ and you use 7fd1a60b01f91b314f59955a4e4d4e80d8edf11d  it will give you the 76294 commit. This happens because we are using the cursor to get the commit after 7fd1.

Comment: @eiu165 Can you edit this answer with the actual query you ended up using?

Comment: @eiu165 Thank you so much. Apparently, you did not use the "cursor" edge type.